How to restrict access to Express JS APIs?
I have developed APIs in express js. (for eg http://api.express.xyz/route1, http://api.express.xyz/route2 etc.)
I am calling these APIs from other domains viz website-1, website-2, website-2
My question is :

how do I check the originating domain of the request, when any of these express APIs are called?

how do I restrict that my express APIs are acessible from these domains only website-1, website-2, website-2?


Am I missing something?

So far what have you done about it ?Show your code. You need to use middleware to check from which domains your express API are being called.

You cant. Use a user based login system or proxy the API requests through a /api router on your webserver that serves the frontend/website, but then they are also not protected and just "hidden". Either your API is public or "private" with user based authentication.

@Subha
Thank You for the reply.
I tried reading following params from the request object, but none of them returned the domain name of the application/site fetching the  API
req.hostname
// returns localhost
req.originalUrl
// returns /api-path
req.get('host')
// returns localhost:port-number
req.get('origin')
// returns undefined
req.headers.host
// returns localhost:port-number

Look into what CORS and origin header are, that will cover some of your use-case. Warning though: they are not a security mechanism for your api, they are a security mechanism for the client using the browser and in no way forbid anyone from just sending you a curl'ed request with whatever headers they please.

Is the issue still persisting ?

@ WeDoTheBest4You
Sorry for the late  reply from my side.
Thank You for such a wonderful detailed explanation, the other day.
What you have mentioned is setting  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" for the response.
But, I want to check the origin in the request so that I can write my business logic basis the origin of the request.
I do have tried CORS in the express js, I mentioned some specific sites in the cors declaration. But cors is not coming into effect nor I am able to see the origin of the request.
req.hostname returns localhost:portNumber only
see my code below

expressApp.use(''/api-pattern*', cors(corsOptions));
expressApp.get('/api-pattern*', (req, res) =>{
if (req.session.views){
req.session.views = req.session.views + 1;
}
else{
req.session.views = 1;
}
console.log("views = " + req.session.views);
console.log("host = " + req.hostname); //returns localhost
//if it worked as desired following should come into effect
if(req.hostname == "https://www.site1.com"){
// send response 1
}
else if(req.hostname == "https://www.site2.com"){
// send response 2
}
});

Please check this : console.log(req.get('Origin')); In the post, under the section server3-2.js, it gives the out as : http://localhost:3000

@ WeDoTheBest4You :  the code shared by me was executed on production in cloud environment. console.log(req.get('Origin')); gives localhost only

Also, to give you all more insight about my api. Not only I want to determine the origin/domain of the request, but also I want to restrict apis to specific pages for each domain basis the api subscription plan. So I also want to check the URI of the request.

In production, the Express App might be behind a proxy. Therefore the app needs to trust the proxy and get some of the headers from the proxy. For this to happen, this statement is required in the production code. app.set("trust proxy", true); Citation : https://expressjs.com/en/guide/behind-proxies.html

Hi, did the new setting work for you ?

Nopes.
As I have researched over the days, I need to develop a system to identify a user (for domain/website) and assign them credentials to access my APIs. This way I can restrict the access only to specific domains.

Thank you for the update. Are you facing issues in the Development stage or after deploying in the Production site ? This I referred to our previous communications. If it is in the development stage I shall try to contribute. If it is a production issue, I do not have an env to reproduce it.

If you want to handle this issue inside your main app, you should use express middlewares due to restrict who can request your application APIs

I have tried CORS , but in vain

Please see the following post. It shows a common cross origin access scenario. How to check origin and how origins will be restricted are also included in it. All source codes have been enclosed below.
The context is as follows:
server1.js

server1.js, listens to port 3000, and serves the file - index.html
The URL to this server is http://localhost:3000
Therefore the “current origin” of the document in the browser will be the same - http://localhost:3000.
This document has a “cross origin” request to http://localhost:4000, please see the source of index.html below to know this in detail.
As we know, since the two ports are different, browsers will treat it as a “cross origin” request.

server2-1.js version 1

server2-1.js is the first version of the cross-origin resource server.
This server listens to port 4000, and sends a sample json response.
The URL to this server is http://localhost:4000
Please note this version of the server does not have set “Access-Control-Allow-Origin”
response header.


As a result, all “cross-origin” requests to this server version will be blocked.

Action 1:

Please executing the URL  http://localhost:3000 on browser
Please check the console in Developer tools, the following error will be logged there.
This is the expected response.

Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:4000/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
server2-2.js version 1

server2-2.js is the second version of the cross-origin resource server.
Like its first version, it listens to the same port 4000, and sends a sample json response.
The URL to this server remains the same http://localhost:4000
Please note this version does set “Access-Control-Allow-Origin”
response header. It sets it to the origin http://localhost:3000.
As a result, the “cross-origin” requests from http://localhost:3000 will be allowed.

Action 2:

Please executing the same URL  http://localhost:3000 on browser
Please check the console in Developer tools, no new errors will be logged.
Instead the message ‘done’ will be displayed. It means the “cross-origin” request has been completed successfully.

server2-3.js version 1

server2-3.js is the third version of the cross-origin resource server.
Like its previous two versions, it listens to the same port 4000, and sends a sample json response.
The URL to this server remains the same http://localhost:4000
Please note this version does set “Access-Control-Allow-Origin”
response header. However it sets it to a different origin as  http://somedomain:3000
As a result, all “cross-origin” requests will be restricted to http://somedomain:3000 only. Any requests other than this will be blocked.
In order to know the origin of all requests, the origin header can be used; this version logs it onto the server console.

Action 3:

Please executing the same URL  http://localhost:3000 on browser
Please check the console in Developer tools, the same error as in "Action 1" will be logged.
It means the server will accept cross origin requests only from http://somedomain:3000.
Please check the server console as well, the origin will be logged over there.

server1.js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

const options = {
  root: path.join(__dirname, './'),
};

app.use('/', (req, res, next) => {
  res.sendFile('index.html', options);
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('L@3000'));

server2-1.js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  res.json('done');
});

app.listen(4000, () => console.log('L@4000'));

server2-1.js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');
  next();
});

app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  res.json('done');
});

app.listen(4000, () => console.log('L@4000'));

server2-3.js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.get('Origin'));
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://somedomain:3000');
  next();
});

app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  res.json('done');
});

app.listen(4000, () => console.log('L@4000'));

index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <script>
    fetch('http://localhost:4000')
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((res) => console.log(res));
  </script>
  <head>
    Test index
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>This is a test file</p>
  </body>
</html>

